# Ruby on Rails using incorrect layout partial

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR app that has some bits under `/admin/` which uses it's own styles and layouts to the root.

I have created a controller and view under `/admin/active_vulnerabilities` but this is using the layouts for root not the admin layouts and CSS etc

I did originally create the controller and view under root but I have moved it under `/admin/` and the routes work fine but it seems to have cached the layouts and CSS for the root and not updating to the admin ones. I have tried to use rails assets:precompile but its still pulling the incorrect bits through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `layout :admin` from `/admin/active_vulnerabilities` controller like:

```
class Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  layout :admin

  ...
end
```

And place your admin layout in `app/views/layouts/admin` file

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your controllers in `admin` is inhereting from `ApplicationController`. If you are not explicitly point layout's name first time Rails search layout by controller's name, then by its ancestors' names. [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts)

- You can do like @AntonTkachov showed:

  ```
  class Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
    layout :admin

    ...
  end
  ```
- Or you can create `AdminController`:

  ```
  class AdminController < ApplicationController
    # some shared code for admin namespace
  end
  ```

  and inherit from it every controller in `admin` namespace:

  ```
  class Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < AdminController
    #some code
  end
  ```